# Proving that $\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^i = 0$ for $k\mid n$ and $\alpha$ of order $k$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, divisibility

I've "found" the following theorem:

If $n$ is a composite number, $k$ is a divisor of $n$, and $\alpha$ an element of $(\mathbb Z/n)^\times$ of order $k$, then $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^i = 0 \mod n.$$
My two pages proof of this result is laborious. Observing that
$$\sum(...) = {n\over k} (\alpha^0+\cdots +\alpha^{k-1}) = {n\over k}{\alpha^k - 1\over \alpha-1},$$
it proceeds by showing that this last expression is a multiple of $n$.

Is there a relatively simple way to prove the titular result?

**Note**: Here are sufficient conditions for the existence of a number $k$ satisfying the requirements:

- if $n$ is a multiple of $p^m$ for some prime $p$ and $ m > 1$, then $k = p$ fulfills the requirements.
- If $n$ is an even number, multiple of at least one odd prime factor $p$, then $k = 2$ divides both $n$ and $p-1$, hence fulfills the requirements too.

In the case where $n$ is a squarefree odd number, there may exist a $k$ that fulfills the requirements. For example $n = 21$ and $k=3$, but that's not necessary (example: $n=15$ or $n = 35$) - thx to @abiessu for the rmks.

Comment: It seems that having $k\mid n$ and $k\mid \varphi(n)$ are not both guaranteed to occur for a given $n$.  Is there some additional condition that causes this to not be a problem?

Comment: If I’ve understood this correctly, I suspect turning this into a problem about roots of unity would be revealing. From there you should find an elementary proof or you might even be able to use some nice facts of cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: @abiessu. If $n$ is divisible by $p^m$ with $m > 1$ for some prime $p$, this is guaranteed with $k = p$. And if n is a squarefree number divisible by at least 2 odd prime factors, then $k = 2$ fulfills the conditions too. The only case where no prime number divide both n an $\varphi(n)$ is whenever $n = 2p$, with $p$ odd. Anyway, the result is claimed whenever the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: It suffices to prove the congruence modulo $p^t$ for every prime power $p^t$ dividing $n$; fixing any such prime, one can prove that $p^t$ divides the last expression using [Lemma 3 of this paper](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/AAN.pdf) for example.

Comment: If I haven't misread things, it looks like $n=15, 35$ are a couple examples that do not fit your claims on when such a $k$ exists.

Comment: And surely $k=2$ works perfectly for $n=2p$ or indeed any even number $n\gt 2$...  My suggestion is thus to simply write the condition as $k\mid n$ and $k\mid\varphi(n)$.

Comment: @abiessu. Correct, I am partially wrong with the condition: obviously, any odd squarefree integer $n$ cannot fit, but even squarefree integer n > 2 with at least one odd factor do fit with k = 2. I'll edit the edit.

Comment: I see that $n=21$ does work with $k=3$, so really the divisibility condition is the most applicable that I can see.

Comment: Actually, whenever you wrote that, I was removing the "necessary" part of my edit.

Comment: I understand that the divisibility condition is somewhat implied by the conditions on $k$, I just think your note would work best with that part directly stated rather than suggesting that a class of numbers should be excluded where some members might be part of the main theorem.  There might not even be a need to go into detail, just say that $k$ has these conditions, and the reader can deduce when they are met.

Comment: @GregMartin. What about posting an answer? I would like to see your method (or at least a summary a bit more elaborated than the comment you left).